# AVPlayerItem Status Observer - Unit Test Status Changes

Tags: swift, unit-testing

Does anyone have any references on unit testing key value observing logic in swift? I'd like to mock the AVPlayerItem's status changes in my unit tests to confirm that the expected logic is triggered. For simplicity this is what I have so far:

A function that observes the provided playerItem's status

```
public func observePlayerItemStatus(playerItemToObserve: AVPlayerItem) -> NSKeyValueObservation {
    let observerToken = playerItemToObserve.observe(\.status, options: [.new, .old], changeHandler: { (playerItemToObserve, _) in
        switch playerItemToObserve.status {
        case .failed:
            // failed logic
        case .readyToPlay:
            // ready to play logic
        default:
            // default logic
        }
    })

    return observerToken
}
```

I've created a mock class, MockAVPlayerItem

```
class MockAVPlayerItem: AVPlayerItem {
    var mockStatus: AVPlayerItem.Status = .unknown
    public override var status: AVPlayerItem.Status {
        get { return mockStatus }
        set { self.mockStatus = newValue }
    }
}
```

My unit test attempting to trigger the status code change does the following:

```
func test_readyToPlayIsTriggered() {
   let url = URL(string: "https://www.rmp-streaming.com/media/big-buck-bunny-360p.mp4")!
   let mockPlayerItem = MockPlayerItem(url: url)
   let statusToken = observePlayerItemStatus(playerItemToObserve: mockPlayerItem)
   mockPlayerItem.status = .readyToPlay

... some assertion that ready to play was called ....
}
```

The logic itself works when I run the application however my unit tests are unable to trigger my observer. I've followed a similar approach to mock `AVPlayer.timeControlStatus` and it's worked great but for some reason `AVPlayerItem.status` isn't behaving the same.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `willChangeValue` and `didChangeValue` in my mock solved my problem. Observers are now triggered as expected.

```
class MockAVPlayerItem: AVPlayerItem {
    var mockStatus: AVPlayerItem.Status = .unknown
    public override var status: AVPlayerItem.Status {
        get { return mockStatus }
        set {
            willChangeValue(for: \.status)
            self.mockStatus = newValue
            didChangeValue(for: \.status)
        }
    }
}
```